# copy file with specific names batch

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy, robocopy

How can I copy files with a specific name with a batch file?

XCOPY and ROBOCOPY has no right key for it.

I tried something like this

```
ROBOCOPY %path_to_server% %collected_data_folder% /S /XC /XN /XO
```

but it copies ALL files.
I want to copy just the files with "_CPU2" in their names.

Comment: `xcopy` allows the inclusion of the file mask in the `source`, while in `robocopy` it is the third argument.

Comment: What about reading the documentation of [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) and [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ROBOCOPY %path_to_server% %collected_data_folder% `*_CPU.*` /S /XC /XN /XO

just added the `*_CPU.*` after your destination path